# Проблемы с github: This pull request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved

Tags: git, github

Обновил некоторые классы для чужого проекта и сделал pull request. Но в conversation есть проблема: "This pull request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved. Only those with write access to this repository can merge pull requests." Как её решить? И автор тоже пишет в conversation: "Please merge from master first and i'll accept the pull-request".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно запулить мастер-ветку автора, и зарезолвить появившиеся конфликты. После этого сделать мерж-коммит и предложить пулл реквест. Приведу пример для tortoise git.

1. Правый клик по директории проекта > `pull`
2. После того, как пройдет пулл, появится сообщение о том, что обнаружены конфликты, нажмите кнопку `show changes` и просмотрите все файлы, помеченные красным цветом.
3. Выбрав "красный" файл, откройте его, появится окно поделенные на три части `theirs`, `mine` и итоговое. Найдите красные строчки, и выберите вариант решения `theirs` - оставить эту строчку как у автора, `mine` - оставить свою строчку. После завершения нажмите `mark as resolved`, и пройдите все остальные файлы.
4. Когда все сделаете, откройте проект снова и убедитесь что все работает.
5. Делайте `commit` и push.
6. Отправляйте `pull request` снова.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял. :)

Comment: сделал как просили

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, сделайте, чего от вас просят:

1. зайдите в папку, где у вас ваша ветка;
2. пульните из мастера новые изменения;
3. конфликты, если возникнут, разрезолвите;
4. коммит, пуш.

Comment: Тоже не понял, что нужно сделать. Вот ссылка: https://github.com/b0noI/TicTacToe/pull/29

Comment: @compl Если не поняли что-то конкретное, то говорите, что именно. Если не поняли всё, то сначала прочитайте инструкцию по использованию git от и до, и, если останутся вопросы, то говорите.